# How do I set up my doInBackground's params in my AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

my screen when I click on a button is slow to load (because of downloading images? the image files are really small though) so I tried to use AsyncTask to help. The program works, but I moved the image loading to an AsyncTask to see if it would load faster and the app crashes every time. I'm guessing it has to do with the way I have it set up. How would I fix it? Would using a runnable thread be better instead? Thanks!

The class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // no title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // set full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // inflate listview
    setContentView(R.layout.gmg);
    **new Load.execute(); // executes AsyncTask**
    ...
    gmgListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gmg_list2);
    GMGListViewAdapter adapter = new GMGListViewAdapter(this,
                                    R.layout.gmg_list_row, rowItems);
    gmgListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gmgListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

The AsyncTask:

```
private class Load extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(GMGListViewActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Doing something...");
        Dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        SparseArray<Spanned> gmgText = null;
        Integer[] right = null;
        SparseArray<Drawable> appIcon = null;
        try {
            gmgText = ParseContent.queryGMGText();
            right = ParseContent.queryGMGRight();
            appIcon = ParseContent.queryDrawable();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Inflate GMG's rows
        rowItems = new ArrayList<GMGRowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < gmgText.size(); i++) {
            GMGRowItem item = new GMGRowItem(appIcon.get(i), gmgText.get(i), right[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat along with line number so that we can know the reason for the crash ?

Comment: add rowItems.add(item); in onPostMethod doinBackground not adding you'r row add this in onpost()

Comment: protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... arg0) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              try
              {
               
                q=(ArrayList) ScanInfo.getFromDump("quatation_type");
               
             }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return q;
          }

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList result) {           
              super.onPostExecute(result);
              if(!result.isEmpty())
              {  progress.dismiss();
              
              sublist.addAll(result);
              sub_type_ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_color,sublist);
              //dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
              subtype_sp.setAdapter(sub_type_ad);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply some changes in your code like...

need to set list adapter in onPostExecute method and remove it from onCreate().

After completing background process it will interact with ui thread.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
     GMGListViewAdapter adapter = new GMGListViewAdapter(this,
                                    R.layout.gmg_list_row, rowItems);
     gmgListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Try this and let me know if you got any isssue.

Comment: Perfect! I was suspecting that it must have been this in my sleep and I woke up to it haha